# How to create an ELF executable on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, nasm, ld, elf

I'm following this tutorial: https://littleosbook.github.io/#linking-the-kernel

and I'm on a Mac. I'm at the point where I have an object file created from `nasm`, and I want to turn it into an ELF executable using `ld`. The `ld` on a mac doesn't look like it supports the ELF format, but I don't want to run a virtual machine with Ubuntu just to do this link step.

Is it possible to install GNU `ld` on mac and run it alongside Mac's `ld` ?

Comment: take your output and run "file -f <your output>" and see what it says.  I use "clang main.s -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -o main" and that gives me "Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64"

Comment: I think that threw an error because it didn't know what to do with an ELF file: "file -f loader.o" gave me "cannot open `ELF' (No such file or directory)"

Comment: If you are seriously looking at Custom 32-bit OS development on OS/X I'm going to recommend at a minimum that you might want to consider creating a cross compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. `ld` is part of GNU binutils. You can build and install it as follows:

```
wget -nc https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.27.tar.gz
tar xzf binutils-2.27.tar.gz
cd binutils-2.27
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --prefix=${HOME}/.local/binutils --target=i386-unknown-linux-gnu
make -j7
make install
```

That installs ld to `~/.local/binutils/bin/ld`. If you want a 64-bit binutils, use `--target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.